# Can UWP apps be ported to Windows 7?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

Can a Windows 10 app built on the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) be ported back to Windows 7 customers? In particular, one made using XAML?

Comment: check out Morten Nielsen's Universal WPF library: https://github.com/dotMorten/UniversalWPF

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I'm not sure where your confusion comes from. The question is about porting.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The UWP platform is only available for Windows 10 devices. We can't port it back.

If you want to use it on a Windows 7 device, you can make a WPF prject, which uses XAML, the same as UWP. WPF can run on Window 7. In particular, the XAML and C# code can be reused.

Comment: XAML is not the same as WPF. They share a lot of common features, but are different enough that only the most simple apps are easily ported.

Comment: XAML is a markup language used by WPF, while WPF itself is a technology. It's like comparing HTML with WebKit, I think.

Comment: In general, people have to know WPF is officially the premiere framework for pure Desktop applications on Windows, including 10. Nothing has been superseded regarding it simply because it still uses a fully featured XAML and C#. It is confusing with all those acronyms about mobile frameworks that use a subset of XAML, but a simple rule to remember is that if it uses XAML and  it is not explicitly replaced by something new on XAML that is not a subset of it, then it's not superseded.

Comment: @jriv I would say UWP has superseded it for Win 10 Devices. But if you need to support Win 7, WPF is still the go to framework

Comment: @MichalCiechan it's impractical since neither 8 or 8.1 can run UWP locally. I get a sense the original Microsoft design is WPF is the standard Desktop way, and UWP is mainly a mobile/Windows 10/scalable way.